# Database query - how I can realize it on console?

Tags: java, sql, database

My current program can write data records in the database (also check if the primary key already exists). On the second step I want to extend my program with the feature that you are able to update/delete a dataset. UserID is the primary key. First name, Surname, Street aren't. But my aim is that you can also search for the first name or other fields, which arent primary, and get all dataset's where e.g. first name = searched value.

How I image it:

```
System.out.println("You have choosen edit/delete dataset!"); 
System.out.println("Enter UserID or other informations");

// Read in all available information from the user 
// 
UserInfo search = new UserInfo();
searchResult = search.getUserInfo(userid, firstname, secondname...);
```

The output on screen should like the following (Searched for Smith):

- (1) ID0001 | Max | Smith | ....
- (2) ID0002 | Justin | Smith | ...

And the user is able to choose the datset by input 1,2... which he want's to update or delete.

Problems which I dont know how to solve:

- When the user haven't entered all information and just searched for eg. surname, how I can transmit the other empty fields, because the method expect also the other parameters.
- When searchResult is an array, i haven't any reference to the database anymore, how I return the result back, without losing the reference to the database, that im still able to access on record.

**EDIT: Using JDBC to connect to the database.**

Comment: what are you using, is it jdbc? Kindly include that information in the question

Comment: yes, im using JDBC. I'll add it to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [**Scanner**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) to get the user input, and search using this input:

```
System.out.println("You have choosen edit/delete dataset!"); 
System.out.println("Enter UserID or other informations");
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String searchKeyWord=scanner.next();
```

And then search using this keyword, or if you want to have many keywords you can use an array:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String searchInput=scanner.next();
String[] keywords=searchInput.split(" ");
```

And then you can manage these keywords in your search like you want.

**EDIT:**

You can change your method so it will expect an array of keywords as an input, and whatever this array contains you will search using these keywords.

**EDIT 2:**

If he skips a value you can set it to `null`, and in your search method you only use the values that aren't `null`.

This is how your search method can be written to take all the parameters, and there you have to test all the cases whrer some fields can be null:

```
public void searchInfo(String[] keywords){
Connection conn = null;
Statement stmt = null;
try{

  Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

  conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);

  stmt = conn.createStatement();

  String sql = "SELECT * FROM my_Table ";
  if(keywords[0]!= null || keywords[1]!= null || keywords[2]!= null){
     sql+=" WHERE ";
     if(keywords[0]!= null){
        sql+=" id= ?";
        stmt.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(keywords[0]));
        if(keywords[1]!= null){
            sql+="AND firstname= ? ";
            stmt.setString(1, keywords[1]);
            if(keywords[2]!= null){
               sql+="AND secondname= ? ";
               stmt.setString(2, keywords[2]); 
            }
        }else if(keywords[2]!= null){
              sql+="AND secondname= ? ";
              stmt.setString(1, keywords[2]); 
        }
     }else if(keywords[1]!= null){
        sql+=" firstname= ? ";
        stmt.setString(1, keywords[1]);
        if(keywords[2]!= null){
           sql+="AND secondname= ? ";
           stmt.setString(2, keywords[2]); 
        }
     }else if(keywords[2]!= null){
              sql+=" secondname= ? ";
              stmt.setString(1, keywords[2]); 
           }
  }
  ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
  while(rs.next()){
     //Retrieve by column name
     int id  = rs.getInt("id");
     String first = rs.getString("firstname");
     String second = rs.getString("secondname");

     //Display values
     System.out.print("ID: " + id);
     System.out.print(", Firstname: " + first);
     System.out.print(", Secondname: " + second);
  }
  rs.close();
  }catch(SQLException se){
      se.printStackTrace();
  }catch(Exception e){
      e.printStackTrace();
  }finally{
     try{
        if(stmt!=null)
           conn.close();
     }catch(SQLException se){
     }
     try{
        if(conn!=null)
            conn.close();
     }catch(SQLException se){
        se.printStackTrace();
     }
  }//end try
  }
```

**EDIT 3:**

```
//Let's say you got a list of User object List<User> ls
Iterator<User> it= ls.iterator();
int i=1;
while(it.hasnext()){
 User u= (User) it.next();
 System.out.println("("+i+") : ID= "+u.getId()+" Firstname= "+u.getFirstName()+" Secondname= "+ u.getSecondName);
 i++;
}
System.out.println("Please enter the index of the wanted result:");
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
int index=scan.nextInt()-1; //index in list count from 0
if(index<=ls.size()){
  System.out.println("the expected result is:");
  System.out.println("ID= "+ls.get(index).getId()+" Firstname= "+ls.get(index).getFirstName()+" Secondname= "+ ls.get(index).getSecondName);
}
```

Comment: I'm read the input line by line. Eg. when im asking for first line, and he haven't the information he can skip with enter.

Comment: Does this also work for the idea I mentioned  a comment above?

Comment: Yes it works, it only depends on how you write the query in your search method.

Comment: thanks for this sample, im trying to implement it. So you would output the datarecords in the same method, without returning them back?

Comment: You can return them, you have only to create a list of objects and in each loop you creat an object an add it to this list, and finally return this list. 

**Note:** Be careful while implementing this query because you have to test all cases where keywords can be null, in order to have a valid query.

Comment: But e.g. when you enter just the first name, there will be proabably more as one result. After outputting the result. How can I refer to the right dataset (choosen by user)

Comment: You can pass the dbname as an input to your method `searchInfo(String[] keywords, String dbname)`.

Comment: Sorry, I misspelled it i mean dataset, not database.

Comment: You can't refer to the right one, there are multiple results from the database, if the user wants only one result he should be more specific entering more details. That's how it always works.

Comment: Hmm, but i would like add such a feature. I mean when the user got 3 results, i count them. He can choose the number (right data record), i can filter out the userID from the output and make a new query?

Comment: Okay then, if they are stored in a list of objects you print this list and ask the user to select the index of the wanted result and using this index you can get the right user using `list.get(index-1)`, take a look at my **EDIT**.

Comment: Thanks alot. Im trying to implement it.